# How can I access elements of a nested list in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

If there is a list such as `[[1 2] [3 4] [4 5] ...]` which is a list of turtle co-ordinates then how can I access the second element(ordinate) in netlogo

i.e for example I want to access '4' of the second tuple (`[3 4]`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`item`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#item) once on your list of lists will report a list. Using it again on that list will report a number:

```
observer> show item 1 [[1 2] [3 4] [4 5]]
observer: [3 4]
observer> show item 1 item 1 [[1 2] [3 4] [4 5]]
observer: 4
```